# python, list, for loop

Tags: python, list

Есть такой код:

```
c=['1','11']
b=['0000']
def ctn():
    for i in d:
        return i
for i in c:
    if int(i)>=1:
        c.insert(c.index(i)+1, b[ctn()])
```

Суть состоит в том, чтобы вставлять в одном списке за числом, которое больше `1`, элемент из другого списка (длина у списков разная).

Знаю, что функция возвращает только один элемент, но ничего лучше пока придумать не смог, может кто-то посоветует?

Или подскажите как объеденить 2 списка `[1,11]` и `[0000]`: объединять надо не простой конкатенацией, а по правилу, раньше это было число `1000011`. Изначальная суть задания была в том, чтобы разбить `1000011` на блоки `1` и `0`.

трай эксцепт пробовал, больше одного элемента из списка б он вставлять не хочет.

Comment: Ничего не понял и код нерабочий

Comment: аналогично, пытался написать что то и отправить но вникнуть в задачу не смог

Comment: Если длина у списков разная, то по какому правилу выбирается элемент из второго списка? В функции переменная d откуда взялась?

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю использовать итератор и генератор.

```
def ctn(a,b):
    ai= iter(a)
    for i in b:
        yield i;
        if int(i)>1:
            try:
                yield ai.next();
            except StopIteration:
                pass


c=['1','11']
b=['0000']
for i in ctn(b,c):
    print i
```

Answer (score 0):

> Изначальная суть задания была в том, чтобы разбить 1000011 на блоки 1 и 0.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.5
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

s = '1000011001110000111110011'
out = []

tmp = ''

for item in s:
    if len(tmp) < 1:
        tmp = item
    else:
        if item == tmp[0]:
            tmp += item
        else:
            out.append(tmp)
            tmp = item

if len(tmp) > 0:
    out.append(tmp)

for item in out:
    print(item)
```